# Webform Submission Using Rest API POST method

Tags: rest, drupal-8, drupal-webform

I just created the webform and added fields.

I need to create a Webform Submission Using Rest API POST method. I just installed Rest & Rest UI modules for this.

But when I try to test my API using API tester its showing the error like this :

```
{"message":"Could not determine entity type bundle: \u0022webform_id\u0022 field is missing."}
```

But I have already determined the webform_id and here is my configuration

POST URL : http://example.com/entity/webform_submission?_format=json

**Headers :**

Content-Type : application/json

**POST Data :**

```
{
  "type": {
      "webform_id": "my_form"
    },
"your_mobile":[{"value":"123456789"}],
"your_name":[{"value":"Test"}],
"your_email":[{"value":"test@gmail.com"}]
}
```

Drupal Version : 8.6.4
Rest UI version : 8.x-1.16 
Webform Module version : 8.x-5.1

Why its not working?

Answer (score 0):

I think the structure of your JSON is wrong. Here is an example that worked for me:

```
{
    "webform_id": "contact"
}
```